# Promise Rejection when fetching video url in discord.js and using the Youtube Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, youtube-javascript-api, ytdl

## Promises with Youtube API Requests

I'm currently making a discord bot in discord.js, and I am trying to make a music function.
Now I know this function works as I have tested it by giving it a set video URL.
I recently tried implementing support for user input (e.g. `$play vfx artists react`, using the youtube API, but I have been met with error messages when I try to retrieve the url.

I know the error is related to promises, as the API hasn't actually retrieved the data when I try to retrieve the title and URL. I am not very good with promises and my attempts so far have been futile, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Code ->

Relevant npm modules.

```
const YouTube = require('youtube-node');
var youTube = new YouTube();
youTube.setKey('MyKey');
```

This is the function where I get the error, I have heard of promises before, but every time I use one I either log a 'pending promise' or I am met with an error.

```
function addVideo(term) {
    youTube.search(term, 1,
        function (error, result) {
            return [result.items[0].snippet.title, result.items[0].id.videoId];
        });
}
```

I then call this function here,

```
searchResult = addVideo(args.join(' '))
song = {
    title: searchResult[0],
    url: searchResult[1],
};
```

Error is found on line `title: searchResult[0]`

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

For those interested, code can be found [here](https://github.com/HatBreakingDad/Moderator_Bot/blob/master/main.js)
I am aware that it is a trainwreck atm, plan on converting it to modules using export / import stuff later.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you so much man. I really appreciate the quick response and I should be able to implement promises in my code now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return`ing from `youTube.search()`'s callback does not do what you think it does. Because Javascript is asynchronous.   `addVideo` returns to its caller long before the search is complete.

You need to do something like this instead to handle the result from inside your callback function.

```
function addVideo(term) {
    youTube.search(term, 1,
        function (error, result) {
            if (error) throw new Error (error);
            song = {
              title: result[0],
                url: result[1],
            };
            /* do whatever you wanted to do with song */
        }
    );
}
```

If you figure out how to wrap the youTube API in a promise, you'll then be able to use `async` functions. That will make your logic easier to read. But explaining all that is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.